# Meteor rendered - access to collection value

Tags: d3.js, meteor

I wish to use template.xxx.rendered to insert a d3.js DOM element svg with
 .attr ("height", **this.mysize**). However, **this.mysize** does not work because template.xxx.rendered is not a template helper and "this" does not return the current document. How do I gain access to the "this" of the template.xxx.helper?

Comment: Please give an example of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the this come from iron router data as a subscription, then you'll have to redo the query in the render. Doesn't lag at all since it's a local minimongo query :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to access the collection in rendered, use a helper function that returns this (or alternately use iron router data context) Then in the template, you can do something like this

```
<template name="yourtemplate">
  {{#with this.mysize}}
      <svg style="height: {{this}}>
        <path ...../>
      </svg
  {{/with}}
</template>
```